# How to check file availability(ex: pdf files) in AWS s3 bucket, using camel exception handling

Tags: amazon-s3, exception, apache-camel

Firstly I got bucketname, accesskey and secret key values.
then I tried to route using :

from("aws-s3://" + awsS3BucketName + "?deleteAfterRead=false&accessKey=" + awsAccessKey
+ "&secretKey=RAW(" + awsAccessSecretKey + ")" + "?noop=true")
.routeId("camelS3Route")
.to("file:storage/data")

Here I want to check file availability.

- file is available or not

-if file doesn't exists then want throw an exception.

I want solve this using Apache camel exception handling

Comment: This route will just endlessly poll and download all files available in the bucket to `storage/data`. Please articulate what exactly you're trying to achieve? Why do you need an exception if you're just downloading all the files from the bucket anyway?